# Yii framework 2.0 Active Record select records with a certain condition

Tags: php, mysql, database, activerecord, yii2

Working with Yii framework 2.0, I have a database table that looks similar to this.

```
---------------------------
| id | name  | key | type |
---------------------------
| 1  | John  | a   |   1  |
---------------------------
| 2  | Lisa  | a   |   2  |
---------------------------
| 3  | Tom   | b   |   1  |
---------------------------
| 4  | Smitt | b   |   2  |
---------------------------
| 5  | Linda | c   |   1  |
---------------------------
| 6  | Peter | d   |   1  |
---------------------------
```

Note that the record 1 and 2 have the same ***a*** key, record 3 and 4 the ***b*** key. I would like to retrieve record number 5 and 6 only because record 1 and 2 are one ***a*** group, 3 and 4 are one ***b*** group, 5 does not have a key pair, so does 6 not have a key pair. The result below is what I want.

```
---------------------------
| id | name  | key | type |
---------------------------
| 5  | Linda | c   |   1  |
---------------------------
| 6  | Peter | d   |   1  |
---------------------------
```

Below is my Model.

```
class MyModel extends ActiveRecord {

    public function getModelItSelf() {
         return $this->hasOne(self::className(), ['key' => 'key'])->where(['type' => 2]);
    }

    public static function getSingleRecord() {
         $allMyModels = MyModel::find()->where(['type' => 1])->all();

         $arrMySingleModel = [];

         foreach($allMyModels as $myModel) {
              if(!$myModel->modelItSelf) {
                   $arrMySingleModel[] = $myModel;
              }                
         }

         return $arrMySingleModel;
    }

}
```

In my controller class, I can do the following.

```
public function actionIndex() {

    $allSingleModel = MyModel::getSingleRecord();

}
```

This is my solution, but if you look at the ***getSingleRecord()*** method. I first retrieved all the records with type ***1*** and in the ***foreach*** loop I filter them and put the single record in the array ***$arrMySingleModel***. I want to avoid retrieving all the records and just want to retrieve the records that do not have a key pair. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

instead of :

```
       $allMyModels = MyModel::find()->where(['type' => 1])->all();
```

Use :

```
       $allMyModels =  MyModel::all(array('group' => 'key', 'having' => 'count( * ) = 1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this sql:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, name
FROM test
GROUP BY `key`
HAVING cnt =1
```

And in AR:

```
MyModel::find()->select('count(*) as cnt, name')
            ->groupBy('`key`')
            ->having('cnt =1 ')
            ->all();
```

Work like that https://yadi.sk/i/dUsqj2yIemvpi, https://yadi.sk/i/kZIltpXZemvsB